# White "holes" in render

Tags: rendering

I'm following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/CwJrb3vjAaA, but I have problems during rendering as white points appear (not visible in viewport).
Switching from GPU compute to CPU didn't solve, neither increasing samples from 100 to 200 (this made it worse, I think), or increasing light bounces from 3 to 12 (3 to 8 for diffuse and glossy).
Denoising doesn't remove them.
Source file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VuUFLp-l7Ytn_mm_W6RVPBDqU7Voa8sd).

[image: Ocean render]

Image blurry due to motion blur.

Comment: Those are likely fireflies" do a search on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! I hadn't deleted the default light source! After deleting it the "fireflies" are gone.